# What is difference between javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped and javax.inject.Named?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In Java EE web appliation I am able to use @Named and @ApplicationScoped  annotations interchangeably as shown below.

```
  @Transactional
  @ApplicationScoped
  public class MemberBankAccountProfileServiceImpl implements 
  MemberBankAccountProfileService {
```

and

```
  @Named
  public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements AuthenticationService {
```

Can anyone tell us the difference between @Named and @ApplicationScoped annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@ApplicationScoped** object is created once for the duration of the application.it can be used multiple time in the application once created.

**@Named** annotation is defined in JSR330  used to differentiate between two same kind of object in same scope.
 This works  equivalent to auto-wiring by name in spring XML.

Hope it clears basic difference.